# Is existence of this set consistent with Zermelo set theory minus choice?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Define a *pre-ordinal* as a transitive set of transitive sets.

Is it consistent with [Zermelo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory#The_axioms_of_Zermelo_set_theory) set theory (without choice) to have a nonempty set $S$ such that: for every element $s \in S$ there exists a pre-ordinal $\beta$ and a set $Y$ such that $s=\langle \beta, Y \rangle $, and there exists an element $r \in S$ such that: $r= \langle \alpha, X \rangle$, where $\beta=\alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$ and $Y = \cal P$$(X)\backslash \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, this is not a theorem of $\sf ZF$. It implies having an infinite descending membership chain in pre-ordinals, which contradicts Foundation. Also, it implies existence of a Specker tree with an infinite branch? Something that ZF percludes.

Comment: No! $\beta$ must be the immediate predecessor of $\alpha$, the idea is that $r$ precedes $s$ that's why the set $Y$ of $r$ is smaller in size than $X$, and this in turn would have a predecessor with smaller sets, etc...

Comment: Ah, I see, there's no "nonzero" clause on $\alpha$. I think it would still be more clearly written with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ swapped (there's no need for the sequence to be infinite in **both** directions), though.

Comment: OK, I've exchanged them. So, now $\alpha$ is the predecessor of $\beta$, and $X$ is smaller than $Y$, however $r$ is still meant to be the pair preceding the pair $s$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that if $s\in S$, then there is a unique $r$ such that your condition holds. Simply because $\mathcal P(X)=\mathcal P(X')$ if and only if $X=X'$. So we can write $s^-$ for that $r$ and call it a predecessor.

Next, consider Hartogs' theorem, but without Replacement. Namely, for every set $X$ there is a smallest type of a well-order set which cannot inject into $X$. The proof is completely Replacement free, noting that we can still do transfinite recursion on a given well-ordered set, as long as all the ingredients of that recursion exist in our universe (e.g. comparability of well-orders, etc.) and so there's a meaning to the statement "Hartogs number" of a set. Let me refer to the Hartogs number of $s=\langle\alpha,Y\rangle$ to mean the Hartogs number of $Y$.

Finally, note that in the proof of Hartogs' theorem we get that if $x$ is any set, then $\mathcal{PPP}x$ will contain a well-orderable set which cannot inject into $x$.

So, fix some $s\in S$, then $s^{---}$ must have a shorter order type of its Hartogs number. But that means that $s^{-6}$ has an even smaller one, etc. And therefore this is impossible since by fixing a well-ordered witness of $s$'s Hartogs number, then $s^{-3n}$ defines a unique point within that well-order which defines an initial segment witnessing the Hartogs number of $s^{-3n}$. But now that defines a decreasing sequence, which is impossible.

Comment: Nice! I thought Hartog's theorem required Replacement. So you construct the decreasing sequence by *separating* on the Hartog number of some $s \in S$ after the predicate being a  Hartog number of an element $s \in S$ (actually of the second projection of $s$). Thanks.

Comment: Just a related question, would that proof still work in bounded Zermelo (Mac Lane set theory) without choice?

Comment: I don't think there's a problem there. All your instances of Separation are inside some fixed sets, and you can use the power set as a parameter when you say something "For every subset" (which is not bounded in general).